# Unwrapping & parsing model errors in Angular after consuming web api

Tags: angular, typescript

I've an api for sales person, which will return model errors like this (on failure of submit):

```
{
"Message": "The request is invalid.",
"ModelState": {
    "sv.Name": [
        "The field Name must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '3'."
    ],
    "sv.Designation": [
        "The field Designation must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '2'."
    ],
    "sv.JoiningDate": [
        "Value for JoiningDate must be between 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM and 1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM"
    ],
    "sv.IncentivePercent": [
        "The field IncentivePercent must be between 0.01 and 999.99."
    ],
    "sv.WarehouseID": [
        "Please input a valid value for Warehouse"
    ]
}
```

}

When the web api returns bad request, the above model errors are returned. I would like to parse these errors and display them serially in the web page as shown in the following diagram:
[image: Errors to be displayed after the form is posted]

I did try:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(modelErrors);
```

But I'm unable to read the data from obj. I wanted a generic code snippet in Angular 2+ for this.

Comment: The field names on your model state are prefixed with sv. which I think might cause problems. Can you avoid prefixing them back from the server?

Comment: I can avoid prefixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the api returns a 500 response with those model errors? I'd do something like this:

```
validationErrors = [];

this.myService.save(employee).subscribe(response => {
       // The first parameter will be from any 200 codes, do what you want on success
},
err => {
      // The second parameter will be from a 500 code, your error object
      console.log(err); // Check out what the object looks like, usually what I want is in err.error;
      this.validationErrors = [];
      for (var errorArray in err.error.ModelState) {
         if (err.error.ModelState.hasOwnProperty(errorArray )) {
             this.validationErrors = this.validationErrors.concat(errorArray);
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: The fields names are dynamic. I need a generic method to handle model errors for any model error.

Comment: I edited the answer. I think this should loop through all the fields in the ModelState

Comment: your code snippet is listing the model fields. I need model fields and the error message like sv.Name: The field Name must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '3'.